# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - c# - Repeater - DataSet

Tags: c#, object, reference, null, dataset

[image]

Hi there, the above image shows the exception i'm getting everytime I filter the DataTable generated from the object I created.

*dtHistory = cBLRead.ds2.Tables["ScheduleHistory"];* --> This actually populates the dtHistory.

*dtHistory.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[ExamScheduleID] in({0})", hdnID)* --> This line filters the rows based on the hdnID...

*rptHistory* is already created in my ASP client side and it will remain empty not until the user clicks a specific row located in another DataTable...

I pinned the dtHistory.Rows.Count to show that dtHistory is not null

How will I solve this one?

---Here's what I want to happen---

Everytime the user clicks a specific row of Examination from DataTable,  a modal which contains a Repeater that shows the Reschedule History of Examination will pop-up.

The modal works ok but the repeater I have made does not. What is probably the main cause of this exception..

Any reply will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure rptHistory is not null at that point?

Comment: Actually I also tried to populate the rptHistory during the pageLoad() just to know if it accepts data... and it works fine.. but again, when i click on the row, I still get similar error..

Answer (score 4):

The exception does not mean that `dtHistory` is `null` but that `rptHistory` is `null`. Then as you are trying to dereference it to access the `DataSource` property it throws.

In the screenshot the `ScheduleHistory` method seems suspicious:

```
ClaretExamSchedule callMethod = new ClaretExamSchedule();
callMethod.FilterHistory(hdnId);
```

You instantiate a new object and call the `FilterHistory` method which throws the exception because presumably the `rptHistory` member is still unitialized.

Comment: Actually I also tried to populate the rptHistory during the pageLoad() just to know if it accepts data... and it works fine.. but again, when i click on the row, I still get similar error..

Comment: Can you give some ways on how will I get rid of this one?

Comment: hmm...you're correct, I created an object callMethod because everytime the user clicks on the row, I call the server side method using the ajax... i have to use [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string ScheduleHistory(string hdnID) to call another non-static method for me to be able to populate the repeater...

Answer (score 0):

You should assign datasource like this

```
rptHistory.DataSource=dtHistory.Tables[0];
```